# Route to separate rack application on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

Lets say I have a Rails app running on Heroku at `www.myapp.com`. I would like to create a separate Heroku application to serve a simple ([Rack-Jekyll](https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll)) blog for my Rails app but I would like this blog to be accessible at

```
www.myapp.com/blog/
```

Is there a way I merge the two apps together considering that they are both Rack based, but keep them as separate Heroku applications and separate git repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **redirect** method.

```
match "/blog" => redirect("http://myapp.com/blog")
```

Comment: Accepting this because it technically could get me what I asked for. I think it would probably be a fragile solution though. In the end I decide to just generate my Jekyll blog into `public/blog/'.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible (currently). You'll need to add the /blog as a gem or engine to the mainapp repository, and then push the combined repository to heroku.